# Which film has the most direct sequels/prequels?

Tags: sequels

With the recent news that Disney has bought LucasFilm and plans to make at least 3 new films in the Star Wars series, that would make 9 films in total (presumably all linked story-wise). **Would this make it the film series with the most *direct* sequels/prequels?**

The Bond series has 23 films, however they are generally regarded as standalone movies, not having any links between them (besides the character of Bond). From research the Halloween series has 10 and Friday the 13th has 12, though again I think those films only share the main character.

I'm looking for **English-language films only, that have had cinema releases** (i.e. not including direct-to-DVD movies).

Comment: In a sense, what disqualifies Friday the 13th from this option?  Besides remakes, it can be argued that its the continued story of Jason Voorhees.

Comment: @TylerShads I have not actually seen any of the Friday the 13th films, so I was just going on very limited knowledge of them.

Comment: How about __STAR TREK__. There are 10 films I would consider "sequels" (the _2009_ reboot is a "prequel", with different actors).

Comment: might reword this to something like "which movie franchise has the longest movie series without reboots/remakes", or longest continues story through prequels and sequels?  I still don't think anything beats Land Before Time though.

Comment: @oliver_c the new one is interesting.  It's a reboot, but done in such a way that it doesn't actually alienate the original timeline, but instead sets up its own universe (that crafty J.J. Abrams and his universes)

Comment: @DForck42 - Yes, they even asked _Leonard Nimoy_ back to play Spock.

Comment: *"however [the bond films] are generally regarded as standalone movies, not having any links between them"* I don't know if I really buy that. The books they are taken from are certainly a series and there re other recurring characters.

Comment: @Oliver_C The last *Star Trek* is also a sequel in that Spock's flashbacks are the last pieces of canon information we have about the original timeline.

Comment: @dmckee - well I kind of agree with you, except the issue with On Her Majesty's Secret Service, being where Bond first meets Blofeld in the novels, but its the second Blofeld movie.

Comment: The recent Daniel Craig films are definitely against the "standalone" feel.

Comment: @TylerShads the Daniel Craig films may follow on from each other, but they definitely feel stood alone from the rest of the Bond franchise (almost like a reboot).

Comment: If there is any relevent information in these comments, please edit it into the question, these comments will be cleaned up shortly.

Comment: *Diamonds Are Forever* is definitely a direct sequel to *On Her Majesty's Secret Service*, despite the lead role going from Lazenby back to Connery. The former film opens with Bond going after Blofeld for killing his wife in the latter. Roger Moore as James Bond visits his wife's grave in a later movie, at least implying that Lazenby's film through Moore's films exist in the same continuity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Land Before Time [series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Land_Before_Time_%28series%29#Films) has a total of 13 movies, they seem to all be sequels.

This compares to Friday the 13th **[franchise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_the_13th_%28franchise%29#Films)** with 12 movies.  However, the newest one is a reboot of the series so, imho, is not a direct sequel/prequel.

Comment: I think only the first _Land Before Time_ film had a theatrical release. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Ahh, didn't see that part of the post.  that's kinda silly imho...

Comment: i always assumed friday the 13th was the franchise with most sequels

Comment: on a different note except the first one all friday the 13th movies look the same :D

Comment: @DForck42 I mainly added that restriction to *avoid* silliness with pointless DVD "films". LBT seem fairly legit, but anyone could make 50 DVDs with some kind of interconnecting plot (heck, you could take every episode of Lost as a film with a continual story...)

Comment: Well, if they *all* are sequels, then what is the first one a sequel of?

Answer (score 1):

Would Shelock Holmes count?  There are many Basil Rathbone films which feature the same characters in the same setting.

Comment: 14 in total. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes_(1939_film_series)

Answer (score 1):

The British [Carry On](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_On_%28franchise%29) series boasts 31 movies from 1958-1992.

Comment: While this is true, basically all of them have the actors playing different characters, so they're not really 'direct sequels' in the sense the asker is looking for.

Comment: None of those films are related plot-wise or character-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Godzilla has the most sequels: 29 in total the king of monsters is the king of sequels

I know it not exclusively English but it has the most. Plus none of the movies tell a prequel story they all come after the original so yes Godzilla is the the king of sequels

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this has been down voted. It's, technically, correct in that there have been many Japanese Godzilla movies. However they may not be seen as direct sequels, as some of them are standalone stories with the single repeating character of Godzilla.