# Longest Continuous Plotline Across a Series of Films

Tags: continuity

After watching the thirteen films in the *Marvel Cinematic Universe*, I've been wondering if there is a longer running series of films that maps out a continuous storyline.

[I've found this article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_film_series_with_more_than_twenty_entries), but I am unsure if any of these film series have reboots, or even if they follow a continuous plotline/timeline.

The *James Bond* series of films features a reboot, but even before *Casino Royale* there didn't seem to be much of a continual plotline across the entire series of films (despite the recurring characters, organisations and themes).

To explain what I mean by continuous plotline, I am going by the following criteria:

- Films set in the same "universe" or setting
- A continuous timeline of events depicted by the films (although not necessarily in sequence)
- Each film should intentionally reference at least one of the other films that preceded it
- Preferably at least one of the characters should be shared across more than one of the films in the series
- Reboots or remakes break the continuous plotline, so these cannot be included (but they can be ignored if subsequent films continue the original plotline)

The important part here is the continuous timeline of events. If a film can be placed somewhere in the timeline of a series without causing issues (eg. characters being revived without explanation, previously destroyed places suddenly restored without explanation, massive jumps in time for the setting and yet the characters don't age without explanation), then it is part of the continuous timeline. Otherwise that film breaks the timeline and cannot be included.

I am more than happy to accept parts of a film series.  For example if twenty of the thirty or more *Godzilla* films all follow these criteria, then I would accept those twenty films as a continuous plotline.

I can think of several film series that fit these criteria, the *Star Wars* and *Harry Potter* film series are two examples. But I am looking for the longest series of films that fits my criteria of a continuous plotline or timeline of events.

Films don't have to be direct sequels/prequels to fit into my criteria - films in the same setting but chronologically spread out, and therefore with different characters would fit the bill so long as they kept to a continuous timeline of events. Also, I would accept foreign language films and films that are TV movies or straight to DVD films.

Comment: Is it "number of films" or "length of time" that matters here? Also, what about television shows that later had films?

Comment: I was originally thinking number of films, but that is a very good question that I hadn't considered. As I am looking to watch a long continuous storyline, I would accept either.

Comment: Televisions shows are not included - I only want films for this answer.

Comment: Films don't have to be direct sequels/prequels to fit into my criteria - films in the same setting but chronologically spread out, and therefore with different characters would fit the bill so long as they kept to a continuous timeline of events. Also, I would accept foreign language films and films that are TV movies or straight to DVD films.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which film has the most direct sequels/prequels?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/6855/which-film-has-the-most-direct-sequels-prequels)

Comment: @Panther Ive explained why this question isnt a duplicate of that question at top of this post and in the comments, but just in case you missed it, I'll put it here once more: "Films don't have to be direct sequels/prequels to fit into my criteria - films in the same setting but chronologically spread out, and therefore with different characters would fit the bill so long as they kept to a continuous timeline of events. Also, I would accept foreign language films and films that are TV movies or straight to DVD films."

Comment: Ok Retracted my vote.

Comment: What question above? There is no question "above".

Comment: The bit at the top of this post that says: "This question may already have an answer here: Which film has the most direct sequels/prequels?"

Comment: Oh, well, it says it only to you.

Comment: Don't know enough about it myself, but the Japanese series "Zatoichi" may be a contender. Looks like 26 films and 100 tv episodes, spanning 1962-2003. Also "Abarenbō Shōgun" (1978-2008) had 831 45-minute episodes.

Comment: The passage of time does terrible things to records, there are now 20 movies in the MCU with three planned for next year, which beats some of these answers depending on criteria for continuity

Comment: @m1gp0z the MCU is the correct answer to this question, and yet nobody has provided it yet...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beating the 14 movie streak of the Blondie movies, we now have **23** movies in the Marvel Cinematic Universe:

1. [Iron Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Iron_Man_(2008))
2. [The Incredible Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#The_Incredible_Hulk_(2008))
3. [Iron Man 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Iron_Man_2_(2010))
4. [Thor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Thor_(2011))
5. [Captain America: The First Avenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Captain_America:_The_First_Avenger_(2011))
6. [Marvel's The Avengers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Marvel's_The_Avengers_(2012))
7. [Iron Man 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Iron_Man_3_(2013))
8. [Thor: The Dark World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Thor:_The_Dark_World_(2013))
9. [Captain America: The Winter Soldier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Captain_America:_The_Winter_Soldier_(2014))
10. [Guardians of the Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_(2014))
11. [Avengers: Age of Ultron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Avengers:_Age_of_Ultron_(2015))
12. [Ant-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Ant-Man_(2015))
13. [Captain America: Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Captain_America:_Civil_War_(2016))
14. [Doctor Strange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Doctor_Strange_(2016))
15. [Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol._2_(2017))
16. [Spider-Man: Homecoming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Spider-Man:_Homecoming_(2017))
17. [Thor: Ragnarok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Thor:_Ragnarok_(2017))
18. [Black Panther](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Black_Panther_(2018))
19. [Avengers: Infinity War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Avengers:_Infinity_War_(2018))
20. [Ant-Man and the Wasp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Ant-Man_and_the_Wasp_(2018))
21. [Captain Marvel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Captain_Marvel_(2019))
22. [Avengers: Endgame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Avengers:_Endgame_(2019))
23. [Spider-Man: Far From Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films#Spider-Man:_Far_From_Home_(2019))

The next MCU film (as of February 2020) will be [Black Widow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe:_Phase_Four#Black_Widow_(2020)) on May 1, 2020 with five additional films listed as part of "[Phase Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe:_Phase_Four)".

Comment: while the studio clearly thinks these are related, they don't contain even a single common character across all of them and certainly no common thread or story that is obvious on viewing them.    so how does that count?

Comment: I understood the criteria to mean that there is a link from one film to another in the series, so they do occur in a timeline of sorts.  The major unifying element is the infinity stones, but there is a series of events that occur before, during and will occur after as well

Comment: Black Window: in a world where windows need to be tinted, one tint application tech is preparing his darkest tint film for the clearest of the clear.......he calls himself.....Black Window...... :)

Comment: @MissouriSpartan Woops! :)

Comment: Not to mention the TV series for Disney+ may also play a big roles...

Comment: They will no doubt have some effect on the continuity, as they have things to expand on or explain, like Spidey leaving the MCU

Answer (score 12):

According to [Wikipedia's entry for *Blondie* (the comic strip)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blondie_(comic_strip)), of the 28 movies made based on the strip, at least the first 14 were a continuous series meeting your definition:

> Blondie was adapted into a long-running series of 28 low-budget theatrical B-features, produced by Columbia Pictures. *[...]*
>
> Columbia was careful to maintain continuity, so each picture progressed from where the last one left off. Thus the Bumstead children grew from toddlers to young adults onscreen. *[...]*
>
> In 1943 Columbia felt the series was slipping, and ended the string with It's a Great Life and Footlight Glamour, deliberately omitting "Blondie" from the titles to attract unwary moviegoers. After 14 Blondies, stars Singleton and Lake moved on to other productions. During their absence from the screen, Columbia heard from many exhibitors and fans who wanted the Blondies back. The studio reactivated the series, which ran another 14 films until discontinued permanently in 1950.

So this is definitely 14, and most likely all 28; I note that the entry for Larry Sims (the child actor who plays Dagwood & Blondie's son Alexander) is listed as appearing in all 28 films along with the two main stars, Penny Singleton and Arthur Lake.

Answer (score 8):

**New Answer**:

It is [The Land Before Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Land_Before_Time_(franchise)#Films). There have been 14 movies in the series, but the 13th one is reboot. So, if we don't count it, there are still 12.

> The Land Before Time is a franchise of Universal Studios animated films centered on dinosaurs. The series began in 1988 with The Land Before Time, directed and produced by Don Bluth and executive produced by George Lucas and Steven Spielberg.

[Source](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/6855/27264)

**Old Answer** (after pointed out in comment)

This can be [Carry On](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_On_(franchise)) (1958-1992).

> The Carry On franchise primarily consists of a sequence of **31 low-budget British comedy motion pictures (1958–92)**, four Christmas specials, a television series of thirteen episodes, and three West End and provincial stage plays. The films' humour was in the British comic tradition of the music hall and bawdy seaside postcards. Producer Peter Rogers and director Gerald Thomas drew on a regular group of actors, the Carry On team, that included Sidney James, Kenneth Williams, Charles Hawtrey, Joan Sims, Kenneth Connor, Peter Butterworth, Hattie Jacques, Terry Scott, Bernard Bresslaw, Barbara Windsor, Jack Douglas and Jim Dale.

**NOTE: There may be many other series in other languages, but one can only say confirm if he/she has watched it.**

Comment: As far as I can tell (I'd wait to see from the asker), the Carry On series doesn't meet the requirements, as it does not tell a continuous story. Each film tells a stand-alone story in which the same actors play difference characters with no reference to previous films.

Comment: Do these films feature a continuous timeline of events? How does the events of Carry On Cleo (set in Roman times) match up with the events in Carry On Up the Khyber (set in India during the 18th century)?

Comment: *"there are still 12"* It seems the OP's looking for a longer series than the MCU's *13* films, though.

Comment: @Jimmery They don't line up at all. There is no attempt at creating a continuity between films.

Comment: There may be many other series in other languages, but one can only say confirm if he/she has watched it.

Comment: @AJ this is what I was hoping for. Possibly there is some continuity in the Doraemon series or the Ultra series? Ive looked about, but not found anything to confirm or deny this yet, so I thought I would come here and ask the question.

Answer (score 8):

[The *Up* documentary series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_Series) currently consists of nine films spanning 55 years. The original film, [*Seven Up!*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058578/), was released in 1964 and featured interviews with several 7-year-old British children from a variety of backgrounds.

Since then, the original filmmakers have produced [new](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066356/) [documentaries](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075610/) [revisiting](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088650/) [the](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101254/) [subjects](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0164312/) [every](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0473434/) [seven](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2147134/) [years](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8929142/). The most recent film in the series is [*63 Up*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8929142/) released in 2019, and there's every reason to believe that the series will continue on schedule.

Comment: Also, there's a [theory](https://xkcd.com/2160/) that all of Ken Burns'  movies take place in a single universe. That's 30 miniseries, even more if you count each episode separately.